# LLVM, get the offset of inside struct

Tags: c++, llvm

I want to use fine-grained offset of each struct element in LLVM. For example:

```
struct A{
    int a;
    int b;
};
struct B{
    int c;
    struct A sa;
};
struct B s;
```

For struct B, I want to enumerate each element inside it, i.e: offset(s.c) = 0, offset(s.sa.a) = 4, offset(s.sa.b)=8. How can I get this information (which API could be used?) inside my pass other than dump()?

Answer (score 10):

Use [Module::getDataLayout](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Module.html#a6d883605206368bc536cc9ded97209b8) to obtain a [DataLayout](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1DataLayout.html) object, which can give you a `StructLayout` as a return of [DataLayout::getStructLayout](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1DataLayout.html#a61135fb8666f0b7a37b4e1bbcf1db131). The `StructLayout` has [getElementOffset()](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1StructLayout.html#a9b53bc4ade993c638837c1344465c1f8) method, that does what you want.

Comment: I use the following enumeration but can only get two offset: 0 and 4, SL is the struct layout:
    for (unsigned it = 0; it < t->getNumElements(); it++) {
        uint64_t offset = SL->getElementOffset(it);
        ......
   {

Comment: It is expected, I guess. This is offset of `struct A sa;` inside `B`. Now you also need to `getStructLayout` for `A`, compute offsets for it, and then add them to 4.

Comment: Thanks, we indeed need to recursively calculate it.